# Accessing Silex Application class from other classes; how to inject?

Tags: php, silex

I'm currently working on my first Silex (2.0) project. I have some [Pheasant](https://github.com/lox/pheasant) models defined, which I can access from within my controller:

```
// it is used both static
$p = \Model\Post::oneById(3);

// .. and with an instance
$p = new \Model\Post;
$p->title = 'foobar';
$p->save();
```

Now, in some cases I'd like to access the Application class within my model. For example, to check if we're running in debug mode (or not). Right now:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    global $app;
    if($app['debug']) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But that doesn't feel like Silex. So I figured I need some kind of thing that'll automatically inject the `$app` class to my models:

```
class PheasantModelReflector {
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(\Silex\Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function __get($className) {
        $r = (new ReflectionClass(sprintf('Model\%s', $className)))->newInstance();
        $r->__invoke($this->app);
        return $r;
    }
}

$app['model'] = function ($app) {
    return new PheasantModelReflector($app);
};
```

This works to a certain level, but always returns a new instance of the Post model when called like `$app['model']->Post`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having worked with Pheasant, I may try to create a service factory that injects the $app (or the $debug var) into your entity class like so (one problem here is that your entity must extend `\Pheasant\DomainObject` and you can't override the constructor as [it's marked as final](https://github.com/lox/pheasant/blob/master/lib/Pheasant/DomainObject.php#L22)):

```
<?php

// in the example below I inject the whole $app, if you only need the
// debug var, inject only that, injecting the whole $app may
// tempt you to use it as a service locator

// creating a new instance
$app['model_post_factory'] = $app->factory(function ($app) {
  $post = new \Model\Post();
  $post->setApp($app); 

  return $post;
});

$post = $app['model_post_factory'];

// getting an instance by ID, here it gets a little tricky
$app['model_post_static_factory'] = function($app, $id) {
  $post = \Model\Post::oneById($id);
  $post->setApp($app);

  return $post;
}

$postById = $app->raw('model_post_static_factory');
$post = $postById($app, $id);  // $id comes from somewhere else

// depending on the PHP version you may try directly:
// $post = $app->raw('model_post_static_factory')($app, $id);
```

The problem with the static method is passing the id parameter. You can import into the factory scope the $id from the outside scope using the *use* keyword, but IMHO this is too magic (though I don't quite like the alternative either). There may be some more elegant way, but I can't think of right now.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, much appreciated. Problem with the static methods is that they're magic, so I can do `::oneByColumnName` etc. Anyway, the factory solution doesn't really improve readability of the code (especially in the static context). Thinking out loud here: I could wrap the Application class and make it a Singleton (not really a fan of singletons, but can't really think of a scenario where I'd like 2 Silex\Application instances), or maybe I could use something like Events to provide the Application class to my Models?

Comment: On a second though you can wrap the [static calls](http://php.net/language.oop5.overloading#object.callstatic) in a class of yours that passed the call to the real class and when you have your instance inject the ```$app``` before returning it (sort of composition but without instances as everything is static)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to generate a new instance of model everytime you need to create a shared service (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html).
For example:

```
$app['model'] = $app->share(function () {
    return new PheasantModelReflector();
});
```

Anyway inject `$app` is not necessarily a good idea, maybe you can just inject the dependency every object has? Something like:

```
new \Model\Post($app['debug']);
```